# How to get parse_json result property ignore case in Azure Application Insight log query?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

The log item looks like below, the currencyamount field has multiple case situation:

```
{ "AdditionalFields":{ 
  "backendRequestBody":{
      "currencyamount":1
} } }

{ "AdditionalFields":{ 
  "backendRequestBody":{
      "CurrencyAmount":1
} } }

{ "AdditionalFields":{ 
  "backendRequestBody":{
      "currencyAmount":1
} } }
```

However, the parse_json log query is case sensitive, **is there any way to get the currentAmount field case insensitively** using azure log query?

The query below only able to get one of the log entry which has lower case currencyamount field.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where apiId_s contains "targetId" and AdditionalFields.backendRequestBody has "amount"
| extend amt = (parse_json(tostring(AdditionalFields.backendRequestBody)).currencyamount)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in **parse Json** we cannot be able to use ***Incase sensitive* Json object**. Instead of that you can use following way to achieve.

```
AzureActivity
| where apiId_s contains "targetId" and AdditionalFields.backendRequestBody has "amount"
| extend backendReqbody = parse_json(AdditionalFields.backendRequestBody)
| extend lowercuramount = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(backendReqbody.currencyamount)))
| extend curamount = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(backendReqbody.CurrencyAmount)))
| extend lowupcuramount = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(backendReqbody.currencyAmount)))
```

You can use conditions like (iff) [Ms -Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction) while filtering the data in a result.

[image]